# Ebook managing tool

Tags: software-recommendation, search, ebooks

I'm searching for ebook managing tool that make possible to search text in all ebooks in specified directory. It would be nice if this tool will have GUI. Something like Banshee for mp3 files.

Comment: What format are the ebooks in?

Comment: mainly in pdf...

Comment: calibre is my favorite. Supports most ebook formats and can manage many ebook readers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an eBook managing tool, but [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) can do full-text searches on various eBook formats (pdf, djvu, chm, epub).

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's not ebook indexer, but can do full text search. This feature is most wanted for me :) thx

Comment: Recoll can index the content of e-books.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ***calibre***, an open source e-book management tool which allows you to organize your e-book library, convert e-books to various formats, and interact with your e-book reader, all in an intuitive and friendly manner. It has additional GUI tools such as an e-book reader and an e-book editor. These tools can be accessed via the main GUI or directly.

**Update:**

You can see the search tool at this screenshot:

[image: Calibre screenshot]

Comment: It's nice but Calibre is not able to search at the contents of books.

Comment: @QkiZ: That's not correct: calibre has a tool to search at the contents of books. Open the e-book viewer: at the top right side of the window you can find a box to search text within the book you are visualizing.

Comment: I dont see anything like that. There is only searching by title or author.

Comment: @QkiZ: See the "Update" to my answer.

Comment: Ok, but this search in one ebook at time. Recoll is searching in whole directory of ebooks.